Header not showing in new pages
new pages that I have made and added to the menu do not have the header showing. The pages are accessible via the menu, there seems to be nothing wrong there, but the new pages do not have the header so I cannot navigate around the website after clicking on these new pages.

without knowing how your site is built or the theme/code it uses I don't think this can be answered by people online, can you provide more information? This is a programming stack so normally code is shared

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
